# How to serialize / deserialize BLOB images in Ktor with Exposed?

Tags: ktor, kotlin-exposed

I am new to Ktor and am currently working on a project where I want to use blobs to store user's avatar images. Now there seems to be no decent documentation on how to achieve this.

As there is no default serializer for ExposedBlob I thought I could try to do this with the same approach I use for LocalDate serialization:

```
@Serializable
data class ExposedUser(
    // other fields
    @Serializable(with = ExposedBlobSerializer::class)
    val avatarImage: ExposedBlob,
    // other fiels
)
```

This is my ExposedBlobSerializer:

```
class ExposedBlobSerializer : KSerializer<ExposedBlob> {
    override val descriptor: SerialDescriptor = PrimitiveSerialDescriptor("ExposedBlob", PrimitiveKind.STRING)

    override fun serialize(encoder: Encoder, value: ExposedBlob) {
        val bytes = value.bytes
        encoder.encodeString(Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(bytes))
    }

    override fun deserialize(decoder: Decoder): ExposedBlob {
        val base64String = decoder.decodeString()
        val bytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64String)
        return ExposedBlob(bytes)
    }
}
```

So far I can store images into the database, but reading them (e.g. via GET-Request) throws this error:

```
DEBUG ktor.application - Unhandled: GET - /users. Exception class java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported
java.io.IOException: mark/reset not supported
    at java.base/java.io.InputStream.reset(InputStream.java:733)
    at java.base/java.io.FilterInputStream.reset(FilterInputStream.java:234)
    at org.jetbrains.exposed.sql.statements.api.ExposedBlob.getBytes(ExposedBlob.kt:8)
...
```

How do I resolve this? Or should I try using a different approach? Or in general: How to serialize / de-serialize Blob Images for network transfer (get / post requests)? I am thankful for every bit of information, especially documentation or tutorials if you guys know some. Thanks <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone interested in this, the issue was this line in ExposedBlobSerializer:

`val bytes = value.bytes`

which apparently reads a single byte. Use this instead:

`val bytes = value.inputStream.readAllBytes()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ApplicationCall.respondOutputStream` method to send the blob bytes. Here is an example:

```
val blob = ExposedBlob(Random.nextBytes(1024))

embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080) {
    routing {
        get {
            call.respondOutputStream { blob.inputStream.copyTo(this) }
        }
    }
}.start(wait = true)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately I'm still stuck. My class ExposedUser contains not only the blob, but also other fields, such as the user name as a string, etc. What I am trying to do is to query all user data via a single route and also get the image as a blob. Unfortunately, sending only the image as a response does not help. Thanks for any further help. Kind regards.

Comment: Also, you can respond with the `multipart/form-data` to avoid base64 encoding.